# What is the meaning of the phrase "load on a factor"?

Tags: meaning

I have come across it in this [article](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/finding-new-home/201902/why-do-people-kiss)

> Among these remaining 42 motives for kissing, 23 **loaded on a factor** the researchers labeled goal attainment/insecurity — motives related to “attaining resources, using kissing as a means, boosting one’s self-esteem, and mate-guarding.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually akin to the idea of a "[**loaded** sandwich](https://jamiecooksitup.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Loaded-BBQ-Beef-Sandwiches.jpg)", meaning a sandwich that has an unusually large quantity of filling.

Both derive from the verb *to load*, of course, which means (among other things) the act of placing items (that make up 'the load') onto something that will carry them. For example, loading a van. When used in this sense, you can say *loaded up*:

> Once we'd packed everything into boxes, we **loaded** up the van and hit the road.

And similarly *loaded on* or *loaded onto*.

> We **loaded** the timber **onto** the van.
>   Once the trailer was almost filled with sacks of sand, we **loaded on** the tiles; we didn't want them to get crushed.

Thus, the quote is saying that 23 of the 42 motives remaining included "goal attainment/insecurity" as part of their (metaphorical) "**load**".